# Magento not rendering my blocks

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I made a couple of Magento extensions with custom blocks for a client. The blocks are being rendered on the home page using the admin panel. Everything is working fine on my laptop (Mac OS X 10.8 & MAMP) using a clean install of Magento, but the very same code isn't working on the server (Ubuntu server 10.04).

Both installations have been done from scratch, so the only thing I can come up with is that it's the version of PHP, Apache or maybe some other system related stuff.

Has anyone encountered this before?

**EDIT:**
Please note that the plugins are working fine in the backend, only the blocks aren't rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this is non-matching capitalization in your block class names vs. file names.  Your server's file system is case-sensitive.  OS X's is not.

Beyond that, check your error logs, and then walk though rendering your custom blocks manually step by step.

Comment: @Alan Storm The weird thing is that my plugins are working, the menus in the backend are even available. It's just not fetching by blocks.

Comment: @JonKoops It might seem weird if you're coming from a simpler system, but it's actually not weird at all.  The menus are controlled by a completely different section of your configuration and completely different PHP class files than any custom blocks will be.

Comment: @AlanStorm I'm unable to find where I've gone wrong. Could you help me out if I gave you the contents of my plugin? (http://g2f.nl/0n68zg4)

Comment: @JonKoops Apologies if I came off as curt, but if you're going to get into developing your own modules you need to be willing to learn to program and debug them yourself, irrespective of the cart system you choose. If you've done that, I apologize, but the description of your problem makes it sound like you haven't.  There's no e-commerce silver bullet — just a lot of rusty guns and wet ammunition.

Comment: @AlanStorm I've tried to debug them but as far as I can see my capitalisation is fine. Maybe I overlooked it, but it'd be nice if Magento at least gave me an error message that something is wrong and what is wrong. It doen't even if I have developer mode enabled. The logs aren't giving me anything useful either.

Comment: @AlanStorm I have to agree, there is no golden solution in the e-commerce space. And that saddens me, because it shouldn't be all that difficult. I jumped from OpenCart to Magento because it seemed te be a better solution for what we're trying to do, but all these XML flows just seem to complicate everything. At least that is what it feels like to me.

Comment: @JonKoops What does `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('featuredtopics/adminhtml_topics_edit')` return? Or, looking at your `indexAction` method in the controller, it doesn't look like you're adding any blocks at all?  Why do you think blocks should render there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32993/discussion-between-jon-koops-and-alan-storm)